# Conservation of the axial current using Dirac equations of motion

Tags: dirac-equation, noethers-theorem, chirality

Dirac equation:

$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu -m)\psi=0$$

implies

$$\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu \psi=-im\psi$$

Adjoint Dirac equation:

$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu +m)\overline{\psi}=0$$

implies

$$\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu \overline{\psi}=im\overline{\psi}$$

Axial current:

$$j^\mu = \overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi$$

Result cited in countless textbooks that I'm messing up:

$$\partial_\mu j^\mu = 2im\overline{\psi}\gamma^5\psi$$

which vanished only for m=0.

I get a wrong sign somewhere. Using the information above I calculate:

$\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_\mu j^\mu &=& \partial_\mu \overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu \gamma^5\psi + \overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu \gamma^5 \partial_\mu \psi \\
&=& (\partial_\mu \overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu) \gamma^5\psi + \overline{\psi}\gamma^5 (\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi) \\
\end{eqnarray}$

Thought just now, do I pick up a minus sign from swapping the order of the $\gamma^5$ and $\gamma^\mu$ in that second term?

Using the implications of the equations of motion,

$\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_\mu j^\mu &=& (\partial_\mu \overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu) \gamma^5\psi + \overline{\psi}\gamma^5 (\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi) \\
&=& (im\overline{\psi}) \gamma^5\psi + \overline{\psi}\gamma^5 (-im\psi) \\
\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful with what you listed as "adjoint Dirac equation". It's mathematically nonsense ($\gamma^\mu$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix, $\bar{\psi}$ is a $1\times 4$ row vector).

The correct EoM for the adjoint field is:
$$
i\partial_\mu\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu+m\bar{\psi}=0
$$

Yes, you do pick up a minus sign. $\gamma_5$ anticommutes with all other gamma matrices.

Comment: of course, result of copy and pasting the dirac equation and changing a + sign ;)
Thanks for the answer! :)